# cURL - How to send PDF file to SFTP server

Tags: php, pdf, curl

I'm trying to send `pdf` file to a remote sftp server using `cURL`. First I sent a `csv` file and it was successfully sent to the server with the correct contents.
But now I'm trying to send a `pdf` file, I does send but the size is `0 kb`.

```
$ch = curl_init('sftp://' . $sftpServer . ':' . $sftpPort . $sftpRemoteDir . '/' . basename($dataFile));

            $fh = fopen($dataFile, 'r');

            if ($dataFile) {
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $sftpUsername . ':' . $sftpPassword);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_SFTP);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fh);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($fh));
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

                $verbose = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);

                $response = curl_exec($ch);
                $error = curl_error($ch);
                curl_close($ch);

                if ($response) {
                    echo "Success";
                } else {
                    echo "Failure";
                    rewind($verbose);
                    $verboseLog = stream_get_contents($verbose);
                    echo "Verbose information:\n" . $verboseLog . "\n";
                }
            }
```

I learned that `pdf` file can't open using `fopen`. I'm not sure if I need another function similar to `fopen` to upload the `pdf` file with it's right size and content. Any possible solution on this?

Comment: are you asking how to upload a file over sftp with curl, or with php's libcurl api? because your question seem to imply you want to do it with curl, but your code example is trying to do it with php / libcurl

Comment: @hanshenrik yes using the libcurl.

Comment: @hanshenrik do you have any solution or sample? thanks